# Ping client LAN from Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, lan

Using some code from codeproject, I converted a LAN scanner into an ASP.NET web application. The app attempts to ping all ips in a given user inputted range. The app works fine locally. However, I wanted to make the app online. Using the free AZURE subscription, I put the site online. However, it does not scan the user's LAN. This might be because it is trying to scan the LAN of the server computer my app is deployed on. I would like to know if using ASP.NET, it is possible to scan the CLIENT'S LAN instead of the SERVER'S LAN. Please comment if you require the code for the webpage. The website should be online at http://nkdscan.azurewebsites.net/index . Please comment if any other info is required.

Comment: You can't ping anything via browser. And your ASP.Net site can ping only LAN where that site is located, and not client's LAN. Thats why such tools are desktop only

Comment: So there is absolutely no way for me to achieve this through AZURE? Some sites like this one can do this. http://www.myria.de/lan-scan/index.php

Comment: well, for this to work your client would need public ip addresses for all the machines you want to ping as well as rules allowing it for the firewall

Comment: If you are using TCP for checking host, then you can probably try to use Flash\Silverlight, and then send collected information to the server. But if you are doing real ping by ICMP, then they won't help. And i don't know about others solutions

Comment: Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible using a server-based scanner, because that server has no way to access the private IP addresses used by the local network.  You can only do this from the inside of a network, which means client-side code of some sort.

The problem is that your local network addresses (192.168.*.*, 10.*.*.*, etc) are not accessible from the other side of your router.  When you connect to a remote server your router does some address translations to make it look like it's sending the request.  If you have lots of computers in the same LAN connecting to the same server it's going to look very much like lots of connections from the same place.

If you want build internet server applications then you need to know the basics of how the internet works, and this is one of the important ones.  You don't have to know how things happen at the packet level (although that's interesting too), but some understanding of things like network address translation is essential.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do have one more question though. How are websites like this one http://www.myria.de/lan-scan/index.php able to do this?

Comment: @user3129956 That particular one uses client-side JavaScript to do the scans, and is limited by the restrictions of that platform.  Specifically the JS script (http://www.myria.de/lan-scan/js/lan_scan.js) uses iframes to issue HTTP or FTP requests to a list of probe IPs and checks the results.  All done on the client side.

Comment: Is there a way to this in ASP.NET?

Comment: @user3129956 Not directly, no.  You can use any client-side JavaScript code you like of course, but that's got nothing to do with ASP.NET.